# how to insert a character after a blank line

Tags: python, regex, bash, sed, awk

I'm looking for a quick way to add a "$" character at the beginning of every line 
after every blank line from a file. 
Example : input file

```
text1  

text2    
text3  

text4  
text5
```

Example output file :

```
text1  

$text2    
text3  

$text4  
text5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '{print}; ""~$0 {getline; print "$" $0}' input_file
```

gives

```
text1

$text2
text3

$text4
text5
```

**UPDATE:**
Adapted to handle multiple consecutive blanks:

```
awk '""~$0 {flag=1; print; next}; flag {printf "$"; flag=0} 1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `lines` is a list of your lines:

```
fixit = False
for line in lines:
    if fixit and line.strip():
        line = "$" + line
    fixit = (line.strip() == "")
    print line
```

The `fixit = (line.strip() == "")` is the test that checks whether the current line is blank or not [the `.strip` methods remove all blank characters (`" "`, `"\n"`,...) at the beginning and end of your line].

The `if fixit and line.strip()` avoids printing a `$` at the beginning of the second empty line if you have two empty lines in a row.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sed 'N;s/^\s*\n/&$/;P;D' inputfile
```

Answer (score 2):

`print open("input.txt").read().replace('\n\n', '\n\n$')`

Answer (score 1):

Another way with GNU sed:

```
sed -rn '1 h; 1!H; $ {x; s/(\n\n)(.)/\1$\2/g; p}' infile
```

And with comments:

```
sed -rn '
  1h                     # First collect all input 
  1!H                    # in the hold space 
  $ {
    x                    # Swap hold space and pattern space
    s/(\n\n)(.)/\1$\2/g  # Globally insert $ after empty lines
    p                    # Print the result
  }'
```

As noted by *potong* in the comments, this solution loads all of the input into memory which might be problematic depending on the size of the input.

Comment: The back references (which BTW produces the wrong answer in your first solution) are not needed as `&` may be used instead. This solution slurps the entire file into memory, so may cause problems if the file(s) are large. That being said perhaps `sed '1h;1!H;$!d;x;s/\n\n/&$/g' file` might be clearer.

Comment: Ah forgot to update the compact solution [Fixed]. I used the back-references so it also supports consecutive empty lines. Your comment about memory usage is important, I'll add it to the answer.